# Apply checkerframework using with task avoidance

Tags: gradle-plugin, checker-framework

I am trying to add the checkerframework to my multilevel project. All works well but I want to implement it by not creating tasks unnecessarily until needed.

See the official Gradle task [avoidance page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html).

To keep things as simple as possible I created a empty Gradle project with no sub projects and modified the `build.gradle.kts` file to look as follows:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.checkerframework") version "0.6.35"
}

apply(plugin = "org.checkerframework")

checkerFramework {
    checkers = listOf("org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker")
    excludeTests = true
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.41.0")
    testCompileOnly("org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.41.0")
    checkerFramework("org.checkerframework:checker:3.41.0")
}
```

Running a build scan via the command line `.\gradlew.bat help --scan`

Saying yes to upload it, click the link provided, enter email and opening the build scan link.

Navigating to:

- the performance tab
- the configuration tab

I can see next to the checker framework that 1 task was created.
[image: Develocity build scan]

We had a look and it looks to be in the `CheckerFrameworkPlugin.groovy` class where the [findByName method](https://github.com/kelloggm/checkerframework-gradle-plugin/blob/ceaec4a2a8ad6a7f605fc8effb4c2913854cc5ef/src/main/groovy/org/checkerframework/gradle/plugin/CheckerFrameworkPlugin.groovy#L354) will go and create the task every time:

```
// To keep the plugin idempotent, check if the task already exists.
def createManifestTask = project.tasks.findByName(checkerFrameworkManifestCreationTaskName)
if (createManifestTask == null) {
  createManifestTask = project.task(checkerFrameworkManifestCreationTaskName, type: CreateManifestTask)
  createManifestTask.checkers = userConfig.checkers
  createManifestTask.incrementalize = userConfig.incrementalize
}
```

How to use the plugin to avoid this?

Comment: I also added an issue on github: https://github.com/kelloggm/checkerframework-gradle-plugin/issues/263